# How to get access to the "unlock" screen for android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

For my application, I am trying to get access to the unlock screen to check if the user messed up while trying to unlock their phone. I am currently stuck on how to get access to that screen. Thank you in advance for all the help!

**
The unlock screen is the screen that when the user wakes the phone up, he/she will have to input their password/ draw pattern/ face recognition

**
Main Question: How to know if the user messed up/ inserted an invalid pattern or code

Comment: You might consider explaining, in greater detail, what "unlock screen" you are referring to and what sort of "access" you expect to "get" for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are welcome to implement [a `DeviceAdminReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html). If the user chooses to activate it, you can find out about successful and failed PIN/password attempts via `onPasswordFailed()` and `onPasswordSucceeded()` callbacks.